# jQuery Mobile ajax listview refresh and click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

We load jQuery Mobile listviews over jquery.ajax

```
$.get('LOADER?......,  
function(html) {  
 if (html != '') {  
      $('#id').html(html).find('ul').listview().listview('refresh');
```

Into this  listview we have an click event for all li-Items look like this ....

```
$('#id li').live('click',function() {  
    if ($(this).data('icon') == 'star') {  
        $(this).buttonMarkup({icon:'check'});  
    } else {  
        $(this).buttonMarkup({icon:'star'});  
    }  
});
```

..but if a click on a Item we habe all two contitions! why?

After a pagerefresh F5 on browser it works fine?!?!?!?

Comment: Could you show more of your code, specifically the $.get and where/when it is called?  Perhaps the HTML in question too.  live() should work for matching elements "now and in the future" on the page so it shouldn't be anything related to when the binding is done as I first suggested.

Answer (score 0):

After a second view on this problem i understand what is the really problem! we have not the problem that we have no click! we habe two clicks before page refresh!

this comes from jQuery Mobile Pageinit after loading this second page...

We resolved this problem in this way:

```
$('#id li').die('click').live('click', function() {
```

Anyway: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP